# JFrame Draw text in a label with a picture

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, layout-manager

I'm trying to display text on a label with a picture and some buttons but I noticed both the image and the text are set in the same place, which causes the text to get overwriten by the picture.

I tried looking for ways to display and set bounds separately but I can't find any, and if I add another JLabel it opens up a new window and I need to use the same window

```
public void carga_img(String name,int cols,int rengs){
ventana.setVisible(false);
//----          
        //Defino tamaÃ±o de la ventana que mantiene la imagen y los botones
        //ventana.setSize(519,391);
        ventana.setSize(415,400);
        imagen=null;
        //Inicializo la imagen que se va a cargar
        imagen = t.getImage (name);
        icono.setImage(imagen);

        //Creo la etiqueta con la imagen
        etiqueta.setIcon(icono);
        //Defino posiciÃ³n de inicio y el tamano de la etiqueta, ancho y alto
        etiqueta.setBounds(0, 0,cols,rengs);

        prev.setBounds(0, 400-88-50, 100,50);
        ini.setBounds(100, 400-88-50, 100,50);
        fin.setBounds(200, 400-88-50, 100,50);
        sigte.setBounds(300, 400-88-50, 100,50);
        Nombre.setBounds(0, 400-88, 100,50);
        Apellido.setBounds(100, 400-88, 100,50);
        Busca.setBounds(200, 400-88, 100,50);
        Fin.setBounds(300, 400-88, 100,50);
//-------           
        //Indico yo administrare como se insertan los componentes en la ventana (null)
        ventana.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        //Agrego mi etiqueta y los botones
        ventana.getContentPane().add(etiqueta);
        ventana.getContentPane().add(sigte);
        ventana.getContentPane().add(prev);
        ventana.getContentPane().add(ini);
        ventana.getContentPane().add(fin);
        ventana.getContentPane().add(Nombre);
        ventana.getContentPane().add(Apellido);
        ventana.getContentPane().add(Busca);
        ventana.getContentPane().add(Fin);
        //Muestro la ventana
        ventana.setVisible(true);
    }
```

(This is for a project at school, so there should be less importance given to running in other platforms)

this is what I got

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmWW4.jpg

this is what I want to do

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fnltt.jpg

Comment: 1) Don't use `null` layout, and don't use `setBounds(...)` as this makes for very inflexible GUI's that while they might look good on one platform look terrible on most other platforms or screen resolutions and that are very difficult to update and maintain. 2) Please clarify just what it is you are trying to create, as it is not clear, at least not to me. A picture of what you're trying to achieve and one of what you're actually getting would be quite nice.

Comment: Added pictures, I don't really want to do that much but just display text to the side of the image, just that.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem looks to be mainly one of your not using layout managers and instead relying on null layouts and `setBounds(...)`. Again, this makes for some extremely brittle GUI's, that are very hard to enhance, debug, or change. Instead, why not let the layout managers do the heavy lifting for you?

- If this were my GUI, I'd make the overall GUI (the JFrame's contentPane) use a BorderLayout, which in fact it already does by default. I'd place the top image and text into a JPanel and place that JPanel into the contentPane BorderLayout.NORTH.
- I'd make the top JPanel use a BoxLayout and then would add my Image-displaying JLabel followed by another JPanel that holds JLabels in a GridLayout(0, 1) (1 column, variable number of rows).
- I'd place my JButtons into a JPanel that uses a GridLayout(2, 4), and then place this button JPanel into the main one, BorderLayout.SOUTH.

For example:

[image]

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleGui extends JPanel {
   public static final String DUKE_IMG_PATH = "https://duke.kenai.com/guitar/."
         + "Thumbnails/DukeAsKeith-daylight.png.png";

   public SimpleGui() throws IOException {
      URL imgUrl = new URL(DUKE_IMG_PATH);
      BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imgUrl);
      ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
      JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);

      JPanel labelsPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = 0;
      gbc.weightx = 1.0;
      gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
      labelsPanel.add(new JLabel("Number: XXXXXXX", SwingConstants.LEADING),
            gbc);
      gbc.gridy++;
      labelsPanel.add(
            new JLabel("First Name: XXXXXXX", SwingConstants.LEADING), gbc);
      gbc.gridy++;
      labelsPanel.add(new JLabel("Last Name: XXXXXXX", SwingConstants.LEADING),
            gbc);

      JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
      topPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(topPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
      topPanel.add(label);
      topPanel.add(labelsPanel);
      topPanel.add(Box.createGlue());

      JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 4));
      String[] btnLabels = { "Previo", "Inicio", "Ultimo", "Sigiente",
            "Nombre", "Apellido", "Busca", "Fin" };
      for (String btnLabel : btnLabels) {
         bottomPanel.add(new JButton(btnLabel));
      }

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
      add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(400, 200)), BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      SimpleGui mainPanel;
      try {
         mainPanel = new SimpleGui();
         JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleGui");
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
         frame.pack();
         frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
         frame.setVisible(true);
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Which displays as:

[image]

Comment: +1 ... See [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html). PAGE_START, etc. is preferred over compass positions (i.e. NORTH). @nIcEcOw brought this to my attention. Now I gotta change my habits :-)

Comment: @peeskillet: Haha, I myself was about to point that out, as soon as I saw these thingies, but good everyone is pointing that out to everyone now a days, for this change to take effect :-) Though the code is actually using one, in the right sense :-) But for `GridBagLayout` this thingy goes too, instead of `GridBagConstraints.WEST` it is now `GridBagConstraints.LINE_START`. But still as usual I cannot stop myself from upvoting all posts, because of the main valuable contents :-)